# Is there any terminology for slope/mean(Y) in 2D time series linear regression

Tags: regression

I am using linear regression to calculate trend of 2D x-y data. (x is time and y is some sensor data)

However, I realized that sometimes slope of linear regression needs proper scaling.

For example, even though data is same, slope can be varied by unit. (kilo-meter, centi-meter ...)

I'd like to extract somewhat normalized trend for time-series data, and one of my approach is dividing slope over mean(Y).

In this case, I think, slope/mean(Y) means that the ratio of change in unit time. Assuming mean(Y) is an estimate of desirable sensor data, I intended slope/mean(Y) can have meaning like "this sensor data is being changed 00% daily". (So, to express like this, it's a little bit different with normalizing data.)

In this background, will there be any proper terminology for slope/mean(Y)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "average of samples."  Regardless, the usual way to normalize data is to *standardize* all the variables to have unit variance.  In your application, the resulting slope will equal the (Pearson) correlation coefficient.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your feedback. I see there is ambiguity in "average of samples". What I meant was simply mean(Y) in time series data. Thus I think it's a little bit different with Pearson correlation coefficient. (For example, if average of Y is 0, slope/mean(Y) throws error, not like Pearson correlation coefficient.)

Comment: I am suggesting you consider the usual standardization rather than the process you propose.  Unless you have a good reason for your formula, it's unlikely to be useful.